# Can't load static files in index.html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm trying setup simple app with node, express and angular2. The problem is that, when I run localhost, open it in browser, I get errors: "*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <*". I think it happens because of incorrect path or wrong code in my node/express files.
For example, when I'm trying open library file in source, I always get index.html code :
[image]

Here is the folder structure:
[image: folder structure]
Below I'll show full code

## **index.js**

```
'use strict'

// require dependencies
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let path = require('path');

// require our custom dependencies
let router = require('./router');

let app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

// get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//share folder with static content
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../frontend/build'));
app.use('/', router);

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Example app listening on port', PORT);
});
```

## **router.js**

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let path = require('path');
let User = require('./models/user');

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('request to', req.path);
    next();
});

router.route('/users')
.get(function(req, res) {
        User.find(function(err, users) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json(users);
        });
    });

    router.get('*', function (req, res) {
        res.status(200).sendFile(path.resolve('frontend/build/index.html'));
    })

module.exports = router;
```

## **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Angular 2 App!</title>
    <base href="/">

    <!-- load the dependencies -->
    <script src="./assets/libs/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="./systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

## **Thanks!**

## **Update**

I changed in **router.js** from this

```
router.get('*', function (req, res) {
            res.status(200).sendFile(path.resolve('frontend/build/index.html'));
        });
```

to this

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.status(200).sendFile(path.resolve('frontend/build/index.html'));
    });
```

and now I have 404 error, files not found

Comment: Why does a `.js` file has `html` tags?

Comment: Express is serving your `index.html` for any request, but when angular loads it will try to get other files like *.js files, so you must configure your express in such a way that it correctly servers your static assets while serving index.html only on your angular routes.

Comment: @Rajesh — From the question: *when I'm trying open library file in source, I always get index.html code*

Comment: @OvidiuDolha — Shouldn't `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../frontend/build'));` do that though?

Comment: @Quentin yes it should, but i suspect it's somewhat at conflict with the router registering `*` that serves the index where the router is used for `/` (so any request).

Comment: Why are you using `router.get('*'`? That is your issue anyway. Maybe the files don't exist in the path it's looking for them and they end up hitting that line of code. Either way that code path (or more accurately where it's being called) is where you need to look.

Comment: also i'm not so sure if the script tags should have a `./` prefix. did you try `<script src="/assets/libs/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>` (without the dot) ?

Comment: Instead of serving the index page with a 200 status code (which could cause other issues) I would opt for a 302 redirect instead, if you insist on that functionality. But really you should be returning 404.

Comment: @OvidiuDolha — Argh. I missed that entirely because of the indentation …although the static file handling is *first* so I think that should still work if it resolves to a file at all.

Comment: @JonathanGray — That would break Angular's horrible approach to The History API (which discourages server rendering and makes it pointless)

Comment: @Quentin I don't know about Angular's History API but I would imagine Google wouldn't give him extra points for the practice. But I did change my comment to mention that 404 would be best.

Comment: @JonathanGray — [The History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) is a standard. Angular just uses it. It encourages you to load the same (content-free) HTML document for every URL and then pulls in all the content with JavaScript. (The good approach would be to bootstrap each page with actual content and then progressively enhance with JS)

Comment: @Quentin I know how that works, I've used it myself when AJAXifying websites. AFAIK a 302 redirect wouldn't cause any issue at all with the regular History API.

Comment: @JonathanGray — If I try to load `/foo/bar` and I get served the index page, then Angular's router code will load `/foo/bar`. If the server issues a 302 redirect to `/` then the browser will follow it, get the index page from there and, when Angular's router code checks the URL it will see `/` and load that. A 302 prevents linking (from outside the app) to anywhere except the homepage.

Comment: @Quentin I understand, but I fail to see how that would cause an issue. Any failed request would be redirected to the homepage and would be seen as a homepage request to the server, even if not to the client. It would still be the same result either way, only with a 302 redirect handling it.

Comment: @OvidiuDolha Yes I changed `router.get('*'` to router.get('/'` , but it still didn't help... Also I tried in index.html without dot `/assets...` - result the same

Comment: @JonathanGray — I just described what the issue is and why it occurs. I don't think I make make that any clearer. The results would not be the same.

Comment: @WhatIsHTML — "I changed in router.js from this" — Change it back … or turn off HTML 5 mode in Angular. You are now getting 404 errors if you try to directly visit any page except the homepage.

Comment: @WhatIsHTML — When you run Node to start the server, what directory are you in and what is the exact command you use?

Comment: @WhatIsHTML — If you add `console.log(__dirname + '../frontend/build)` to your server side code: What does it output?

Comment: @Quentin I understand what you mean but think about what my suggestion is improving. He is serving the index page at the directory of another page that doesn't exist. Replacing that with a 3xx redirect is equivalent to that in how the page is rendered, as the browser *automatically* handles the change. It's completely transparent.

Comment: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../frontend/build'));`
hey guys, it works!

Comment: @JonathanGray — "the browser automatically handles the change" — That isn't true when you add Angular to the mix. The browser gets the redirect, the browser transparently goes to the homepage, Angular runs, Angular looks at the URL, Angular sees the URL for the homepage, Angular loads the homepage. It fails to load `/foo/bar` because you redirected away from there.

Comment: @Quentin Anything loaded from AJAX with a 3xx redirect will simply load the content without any way to tell that the redirect even happened. I know the API for AJAX and it simply does not return that kind of information. If the user happened to go directly to the page, the browser would simply redirect to the homepage. In neither of these situations will this have a negative impact. Importantly, index.html is a static page. You've made many mistakes so far that I haven't even bothered to point out and frankly I'm not willing to argue about this any further.

Comment: @JonathanGray — "Anything loaded from AJAX with a 3xx redirect" — The page isn't loaded by Ajax. The page is loaded normally in the browser (after being redirected to `/`). **Then** the JavaScript in the page runs. Then the JS in the page reads `location.href` and sees it is on the homepage. Then the JS in the page makes all the Ajax requests to display the homepage instead of the page the link pointed to.

Comment: @JonathanGray — "If the user happened to go directly to the page" — Yes, that's what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Quentin So the user actually gets redirected to the homepage instead of the homepage rendering on a non-existent page. What exactly does that break?

Comment: @JonathanGray — "In neither of these situations will this have a negative impact." — It makes it impossible to link, from outside the site, to any page except the homepage. It makes it impossible to middle click / right click and pick from the menu to open a link in a new window or tab without being redirected to the homepage. Those are negative effects.

Comment: @JonathanGray — "instead of the homepage rendering on a non-existent page" — No. The user gets redirected to the homepage instead of Angular loading the content for `/foo/bar`

Comment: @Quentin The 3xx redirect, again, is for non-existent pages. Pages that exist will be caught by this line `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../frontend/build'));`....

Comment: @JonathanGray — All angular routes are "non-existent pages" by that definition … unless you plan to copy/paste your index.html into a static file for each and every single route.

Comment: @Quentin This is becoming a really stupid argument. I'm specifically referring to the line `router.get('*'` which is obviously in there to catch what should be 404 errors and renders the homepage instead. If you don't understand by now, then I give up. Have a nice day.

Comment: @JonathanGray — No. It isn't there to catch 404 errors. It is there to serve the HTML that bootstraps Angular when a route that isn't the homepage is deep linked to. It's an approach to implement [this requirement from the Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side).

Comment: @Quentin The star (*) refers to EVERYTHING that matches the route (/) (so basically everything), as long as it doesn't match a previous route. Plus it's the last route. That's basically 404's job. You obviously don't understand. Bye.

Comment: @JonathanGray — I never said Angular's approach to implementing HTML 5 mode wasn't awful (heck, my first comment to you described it as "horrible"). The approach they recommend replaces a lot of what should be 404 errors with whatever the default route is set up to do in Angular. Getting rid of it replaces a lot of what should be specific pages with 404 errors (or, if you put a redirect in there, it replaces both what should be specific pages *and* 404 errors with the homepage).

Comment: @Quentin It seems to me that you're also misunderstanding Angular's recommended implementation. There is never any need to match non-existent pages. You can add routes for non-existent files, sure. But there is never a reason to have to account for http://yoursite.org/balsnelgbneuysrguisergbio

Comment: @JonathanGray — Then you have to make a server side route explicitly for every Angular route you have (and not **just** burn the existing `*` routes). Which would be a better approach (and if you follow through with proper progressive enhancement it would be a good approach) but it isn't what Angular suggest, it is a significant amount of work, it isn't what you have come close to recommending until now. (It is also what I recommended in my comment starting "The History API is a standard")

Comment: @Quentin I don't think you understand how routes work. The `use` method adds callbacks that get called for anything (with an optional route to match) and passes the result along in a chain to the next `use` and so-on until it finds a specific route to match. But it will only match a single route in the end. It simply searches the routes in the same order they are added in to find it. So if you have a wildcard route at the end, as in this case, that will only match anything you don't already have a route defined for. So putting in a 3xx redirect here will not affect actual routes.

Comment: @JonathanGray — Putting in a 3xx redirect will affect actual routes, because when you **deep link** to `/foo/bar` the browser will request `/foo/bar`, get redirected to `/`, load Angular, look at `location.href`, see it is on `/`, and look for an Angular route which matches `/` instead of an a Angular route that matches `/foo/bar`. The `/foo/bar` route will only work when following links from within Angular that get captured by Angular instead being requested directly from the server by the browser.

Comment: @Quentin It's as if you're not even paying attention to what I'm writing, like all you care about is being right. If that route affected other routes then the entire site would do nothing but display the homepage unless that route were removed. That's the exact logic of that route, after all. But that's obviously not the issue, the issue was a missing slash.

Comment: @JonathanGray — "It's as if you're not even paying attention to what I'm writing, like all you care about is being right." — Funny, I was thinking something very similar. "If that route affected other routes then the entire site would do nothing but display the homepage unless that route were removed." — With respect to deep linking, a server side route that redirected to the homepage would have exactly that effect. "But that's obviously not the issue, the issue was a missing slash." — Well yes, but you've still recommended something that breaks deep links that the OP says they implemented.

Comment: And just to make my last comment clear: I said **with respect to deep linking**. Not links from within the Angular app. Deep links. Links from outside the app. Middle clicking on a link to open in a new tab. Not a regular click on a link in a page that would be intercepted by JS event handlers set up by Angular.

Comment: @Quentin Okay, I'm starting to see what you mean, but the OP implemented it incorrectly regardless. The OP is using `express.static()` very early on and additionally is using `sendFile` to send the homepage statically. With this specific logic my redirect would not break things. If the OP had set it up properly that might be a different story. So technically I'm not wrong, but in the correct circumstance you wouldn't have been either.

Comment: Using `static` early is important: You need to handle static files before the generic fallback handler for Angular routes. The code in the question was only failing because the directory path was wrong, so the static handler never found the files and always fell over onto the generic fallback handler for Angular routes.

Comment: @Quentin What I mean is he's still sending the homepage statically in all instances, not dynamically. Statically the 3xx redirect would not break things. Dynamically sending the homepage is a different story. There is no angular code in the post server-side that modifies the page.

Comment: "additionally is using sendFile to send the homepage statically" — That would be pointless in *most* cases because `static` should be able to handle it; but this app is using Angular. The problem is that `index.html` "isn't really" the homepage. It's a bootstrap for Angular and the homepage is rendered by client side JavaScript. That bootstrap HTML needs to be loaded for every Angular route.

Comment: @Quentin I understand all of that (now). What I mean is the "bootstrap" is being served with `<base href="/">` for all pages using the current logic. There is no current possible server-side logic to modify it depending on its actual location. Just look at it.

Comment: @JonathanGray — `<base href="/">` means that you can say `src="./systemjs.config.js"` and have it resolve correctly even if you are loading `/foo/bar` (the browser won't try to load `/foo/bar/systemjs.config.js` it will load `/systemjs.config.js`). It is there so you **can** respond to a request for `/foo/bar` with `200 index.html` instead of `302 Go To /`. (So that when Angular looks at the URL it sees `/foo/bar` and not `/` so Angular loads the correct Angular route)

Comment: @Quentin I know that. Please bear with me. The code sends the actual html file, statically, without the possibility of the `<base href="/">` being anything other than `<base href="/">` through `sendFile`. This is what is supposed to break with the redirect, no? I'm pointing out that with the current implementation it's *already* broken in the same way.

Comment: "This is what is supposed to break with the redirect, no? " — No. What breaks with the redirect is the JavaScript that looks at `location.href` to determine what route to run. `<base>` has no effect on the value of `location.href`.

Comment: @Quentin I understand. So every page is a valid page and client-side JavaScript handles everything based off of nothing more than the location of the page (I guess if you would have put it like that I would have probably understood). That's so stupid though. It can't even not look like a horrible mistake. I don't understand why tf anyone would need routes set up for arbitrary pages. It doesn't even make sense development-wise. PHP makes so much more sense compared to that, and I'd prefer to use Node when possible.

Comment: @JonathanGray — There are many things about Angular that I don't like :/

Comment: @Quentin I'm sorry for arguing with you, I was most definitely wrong here. I hope you understand. I blame Angular for actually doing that though. Such a confusing decision and method. lol

Comment: Angular doesn't take a great approach or clearly explain what it is doing :(